# 'grunt svg' task throws error on directory-colorfy

Tags: javascript, svg, gruntjs, task

I'm trying to run a grunt task to build svg icons using grunt-icon and got this error:

```
Running "directory-colorfy" task
Error: Command failed: /Users/x../x../node_modules/directory-colorfy/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /Users/x../x../node_modules/directory-colorfy/lib/phantomscript.js %3Csvg%20data-name=%22Layer%201%22%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width=%226.64%22%20height=%2211.36%22%20viewBox=%220%200%206.64%2011.36%22%3E%3Ctitle%3Ecaret-right%3C/title%3E%3Cpath%20data-name=%22Shape%201%20copy%205%22%20d=%22M.76.67l4.52%205-4.52%205%22%20fill=%22none%22%20stroke=%22#696158%22%20stroke-width=%222%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E caret-right-tertiary.svg #D86018

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:477:12)
```

I tried:

- reinstalling grunticon globally
- reinstalling phantomjs as a dev dependency
- running the task 'grunt svg' again

without success.

Any pointers on how I can get this working would be super.